# how to convert pdf file to excel file using python

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, tabula, convertto-json

I want to convert a pdf file into excel and save it in local via python.
I have converted the pdf to excel format but how should I save it local?

*my code:*

```
df = ("./Downloads/folder/myfile.pdf")
tabula.convert_into(df, "test.csv", output_format="csv", stream=True)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify your whole output path instead of only *output.csv*

```
df = ("./Downloads/folder/myfile.pdf")
output = "./Downloads/folder/test.csv"
tabula.convert_into(df, output, output_format="csv", stream=True)
```

*Hope this answers your question!!!*

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the script below worked:

```py
import tabula

df = tabula.read_pdf(r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\folder\3.pdf', pages='all')
tabula.convert_into(r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\folder\3.pdf', r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\folder\test.csv' , output_format="csv",pages='all', stream=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

i use google collab

## install the packege needed

```
!pip install tabula-py
!pip install pandas
```

## Import the required Module

```
import tabula
import pandas as pd
```

## Read a PDF File

```
data = tabula.read_pdf("example.pdf", pages='1')[0] # "all" untuk semua data, pages diisi nomor halaman
```

## convert PDF into CSV

```
tabula.convert_into("example.pdf", "example.csv", output_format="csv", pages='1') #"all" untuk semua data, pages diisi no halaman
print(data)
```

## to convert to excell file

```
data1 = pd.read_csv("example.csv")
data1.dtypes
```

## now save to xlsx

```
data.to_excel('example.xlsx')
```

Comment: Please fix the broken code blocks at the end of your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://www.pydoc.io/pypi/tabula-py-0.9.0/autoapi/wrapper/index.html#wrapper.wrapper.convert_into) says that:

> Output file will be saved into output_path

**output_path** is your second parameter, "test.csv". I guess it works fine, but you are loking it in the wrong folder. It will be located near to **your script** (to be strict - in [current working directory](https://techibee.com/python/get-current-directory-using-python/2790)) since you didn't specify full path.

Answer (score 0):

PDF to .xlsx file:

```
for item in df:
   list1.append(item)
df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df.to_excel('outputfile.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `camelot` in combination with `pandas`

```
import camelot
import pandas
tables = camelot.read_pdf(path_to_pdf, flavor='stream',pages='all')
df = pandas.concat([table.df for table in tables])
df.to_csv(path_to_csv)
```